# Couchbase failure to find bucket local instance

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

Following the implementation guide from Spring on creating CouchbaseConfig by extending AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.

Problem #1
My local Couch instance exists on "http://localhost:5984/"  At application runtime the default port always results in the value "11210" which ultimatly results in connectivity failure.

Solution
To resolve this issue I am overriding the implementation which creates CouchbaseClient within my CouchbaseConfig component (Code snippet below)

```
public CouchbaseClient couchbaseClient() throws Exception {
        CouchbaseClient client = null;
        URI local=new URI("http://127.0.0.1:5984");
        List<URI> baseURIs=new ArrayList<URI>();
         baseURIs.add(local);
        client = new CouchbaseClient(baseURIs, bucketValue, "");
```

......

I am still not able to locate the bucket I have setup in my local couch instance

```
http-bio-8080-exec-25] INFO  18:18:14,172 SLF4JLogger.log(87) - Could not fetch config from http seed nodes.
com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationException: Configuration for bucket "bucketValue" was not found in server list ([http://127.0.0.1:5984]).
    at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readPools(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:271)
    at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.getBucketConfiguration(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:143)
    at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider.bootstrapHttp(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:351)
```

Any information on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

So, I think what you have done here is confused `Couchbase` and `CouchDb` - they are entirely different platforms, even though they have confusingly-similar names.

You need to install a local instance of Couchbase if that is what you are trying to do, and get rid of Couchdb.